# how to replace all selected character from string in firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to replace `"` and `/` from my string

[image]

but this string function only replaces the first occurrence of the character and leaves rest

```
exports.customerCancel =functions.database.ref(`/test`)
.onUpdate(async(change, context) => {
    var status = change.after.val();
    sta = String(status).replace("a","m");
    database.ref(`/result`).set(sta);
});
```

[image]

how can I replace all characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `global` flag with RegEx to remove all occurrences of those characters:

```
exports.customerCancel =functions.database.ref(`/test`)
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
  const status = change.after.val();
  const sta = status.replace(/["\\]/g,"")
  //                           ^    ^<--global flag
  //   characters to remove -->^

  return database.ref(`/result`).set(sta);
});
```

Read more about RegEx Global flag at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global).

Comment: not working>>>  i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-customerCancel"
>  undefinedseomRandomStringundefined

Comment: @RoySougat your code does not have any `vendor` field. You should share exact same code so we can spot it,.

Comment: exports.test =functions.database.ref(`/test`)
.onUpdate(async(change, context) => {
 const vendor = change.after.val();

 console.log(vendor);
 console.log(vendor.replace(/["\\]/g), "");
 
});

Comment: result i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-test"
>  "\"abc123\""
i  functions: Finished "us-central1-test" in ~1s
>  undefinedundefinedundefinedabc123undefinedundefinedundefined

Comment: The regex is `replace(/["\\]/g)`, there are double `\\\`

Comment: minor tyop from your side  corrected it console.log(vendor.replace(/["\\]/g,'')); thanks

Comment: Thats not a typo.... single '\' will escape the `]`. You do need them twice.

Comment: no your closing bracket was misplaced rest is ok

Comment: @RoySougat can you update your question with exact code that you have now? let me try copying the function .

Comment: i have solved the issue with your help thanks